# Can I take derivative of a function that represents a piece of music?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, sound

Can I take the derivative of a function that represents a piece of music? The music is given in .mp3, .midi or whatever comes in handy.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?  Do you want to take the derivative of a discrete-time sampled waveform?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry, forgot that mp3 is not continuous waveform. Is the waveform of MIDI continuous/is there a simple way to perform fourier transform on a MIDI input?

Comment: Midi is like sheet music. If you want a waveform, convert mp3->wav with any external tool (this is easy to do) and then import the wav and work on it as bill sugested

Comment: If the input is a MIDI, the following is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592596/exporting-sounds-as-wav-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mathematica, you can read in .wav files using `Import`. Since the data is then a discrete data sequence, you can't take a real calculus-style derivative, but you can take the derivative numerically, for instance, using functions like `Differences` and `DerivativeFilter` (thanks Jens). In fact, the derivative operation is a kind of high-pass filter, which will augment the noise and remove the low frequencies. You can listen to the changed sound using `SampledSoundFunction` or by saving the result out to a .wav file using `Export`. There are plenty of other ways you can manipulate the sound: `LowpassFilter` and `HighpassFilter` come to mind.

Comment: Don't forget `DerivativeFilter` for lists.